# Git Merging into single commit after resolving conflicts

Tags: git, github

Hi I am beginner in Git

I have two commits A and B.
B is a resolve merge conflict commit from master branch to my branch (I pulled from master and got merge conflict).
I have pushed those commits .
I want to merge them into a single commit.

Commit A : My commit with my changes in my_branch
Commit B: Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/repo_name into my_branch

How can I do that ?

Note: I tried git rebase -i HEAD~2 with squash commit (It shows master commits and file changes on my branch )

I used git commit --amend This also didn't work

I also used   git rebase --onto B A Which actually removed all the resolve merge conflict changes

git log --oneline graph B output:

```
*   B (HEAD -> my_branch, origin/my_branch) Merge branch 'master' of https://github.ibm.com/repo_name into my_branch
|\
| *   C Commit from master branch
| |\
| | * D Commit from master branch 
| * |   E Merge pull request #268 from other branch
| |\
```

Comment: Can you explain what `A` is ? I think you want to use `git reset --soft [some commit]` followed by `git commit`, I'm just not sure if you want to use `A`, `A^` (the parent of `A`) or some other commit (the result of the merge ?)

Comment: When you rebase over a merge commit, Git sometimes will completely ignore it (since a merge commit has two parents).  Generally, you _don't_ rebase a portion of the history which has one or more merge commits.  Why do want to do this?

Comment: If you can : add the output of `git log --oneline --graph B` to your question

Comment: @LeGEC Added output for `git log --oneline --graph B`

Comment: Thanks. 1: I imagine `A` would be the first parent of `B`, correct ? 2: do you want to combine together `A` and `B`, and forget that `B` was ever the result of merging `C` with `A` ?

Comment: @LeGEC 1:Yes A will be parent of B. 2. Yes I want to combine A and B. I also want that other commits from master C D E are preserved and they don't in my branch as new commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly : you want to replay `A+B` on top of `C`, instead of having a merge commit with two ancestors.

Here is a way to do that from your situation :

```
# from your branch 'my_branch' :
git reset --soft C
git commit
```

---

Next time, you can use `git pull --rebase` to ask git to use "rebase" instead of "merge" when combining your local branch with the remote branch.

If you think you will want to use "rebase" in all situations, you can make this the default behavior on your computer :

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

Comment: I really agree that `git pull -r` is way more efficient than the merge.